# azure devops for ADF and databricks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to create an azure ci/cd pipeline for my azure data factory in which I have used databricks notebook. Pipeline got created successfully with the ARM template for ADF but I am not able to see any override parameter for databricks workspace URL, that's why i got the same databricks URL in my dev and prod environment.

Can anyone help me to set databricks workspace URL for Dev and prod dynamically?

Comment: all linked services, including the databricks ones, are parameterised by default. Can you see any other linked services? What ARM parameter templates do you have?

Comment: It showing me only data bricks accessToken in ARM parameters but i also want "Databrick Workspace URL" as parameters as its it different for every environment.

Comment: This is the way I fixed that.... ask questions if you can't follow it. https://www.keepsecure.ca/blog/fixing-adf-databricks-linked-service/

Comment: Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818057/how-to-implement-devops-on-adf-with-databricks-activity

Comment: Thanks, resolved my problem by referring to these two urls. In ADf go to ARM template -> Edit Parameter Configuration and added  "domain" propery under linkedServices.

Comment: @Jaydeepsinh You can post an answer to end this question. Your answer can be benefit to others.

Comment: @Jaydeepsinh if you could take the time to summarise your solution as an answer, that means we won't suffer from broken links _and_ you can accept it. If you don't do it in the next few days I'll do it.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone facing the same challenge, I just added this code to my *arm-template-parameters-definition.json*:

```
"AzureDatabricks": {
            "properties": {
                "typeProperties": {
                    "domain": "=",
                    "existingClusterId":"=",
                    "accessToken": {
                        "secretName": "="
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It will make the parameters explicit to be overriden.

If you are using the default template provided by Microsoft, I inserted the code just under the "ODBC" section factories/linkedServices.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a token in qa and prod and use that in ur ci cd pipeline..tokens are unique all
over and automatically linked to respective service